# Obtener Ruta de imagen en Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Que tal estoy utilizando la librería ImagePicker en Swift (https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker) para poder seleccionar multiples imágenes así como poder tomar fotografías, todo bien hasta que tengo que obtener la ruta de las imágenes ya que me regresa ese valor "[<UIImage:0x281e38ab0 anonymous {1080, 1080}>, <UIImage:0x281e38120 anonymous {1080, 1080}>]
[<UIImage:0x281e250e0 anonymous {750, 1236}>, <UIImage:0x281e39a70 anonymous {720, 1280}>, <UIImage:0x281e399e0 anonymous {1080, 1080}>, <UIImage:0x281e398c0 anonymous {1080, 1080}>]"
el código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
      let config = Configuration()
      config.doneButtonTitle = "Finalizar"
      config.noImagesTitle = "Aun no tienes imagenes disponibles"
      config.recordLocation = false
      config.allowVideoSelection = true
      config.showsImageCountLabel = true
      let imagePicker = ImagePickerController(configuration: config)
      imagePicker.delegate = self
      present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    }
    
    func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //Metodo para obtener la imagen
        
        let urlImage = images.description
        print(urlImage)

        
    }
    
    func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema, porque mencionas que si obtienes los valores en un array.

Comment: el problema es que necesito una salida o una ruta como esta: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9988C0CB-421A-404B-83E0-AF1FFD8E8C7B/tmp/output.mov ya sea con video o con fotos necesito su ruta y no como la obtengo actualmente

Comment: En el repo hay una función `getImage()` en `/Source/AssetManager.swift`, mira si puedes acceder a esa función.

Comment: si pude acceder a el contiene este código `  public static func getImage(_ name: String) -> UIImage {
    let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(displayScale: 3)
    var bundle = Bundle(for: AssetManager.self)

    if let resource = bundle.resourcePath, let resourceBundle = Bundle(path: resource + "/ImagePicker.bundle") {
      bundle = resourceBundle
    }

    return UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: traitCollection) ?? UIImage()
  }`

Comment: Me refería a que llames a esa función después de `print(urlImage)`, haz un print del `bundle` y `path` dentro de esa función.

Comment: intente y no pude, conocerás alguna manera de hacer una selección múltiple de imágenes desde galería y obtener su ruta de almacenamiento

Comment: El repo trabaja con un Collection View en donde almacena las imágenes, no he visto en ninguna otra función que almacene en el Directorio de tu app. La única manera es que trabajes con el Collection View directamente.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias seguire intentando